# MySQL not displaying shortest result first

Tags: sql, mysql

We have a standard MySQL 5.1 database with a table named places. We have two columns, name and name_bg, where name is the english name of the place and name_bg is the bulgarian name of the place.

We have two places that starts with "РИМ". "Рим" and "Римини".

```
+--------+--------+--------------+
| id     | name   | name_bg      |
+--------+--------+--------------+
| 221543 | Rimini | Римини       |
|  34514 | Rome   | Рим          |
+--------+--------+--------------+
```

When searching like this:

```
select id, name from places where name like 'рим%';
```

Or like this:

```
select id, name from places where name_bg like 'рим%';
```

Everything looks fine.

The weird stuff is when searching like this (the GROUP BY clause):

```
SELECT places.name, places.name_bg, places.country_id, countries.continent_id WHERE places.name LIKE 'рим%' OR places.name_bg LIKE 'рим%' ORDER ("CHAR_LENGTH(places.name), CHAR_LENGTH(places.name_bg), countries.continent_id, places.popular DESC") GROUP BY country_id LIMIT 10
```

The query returns Римини first instead of Рим.

We have tryed order and group on the query but nothing helped.

Even switched the IDs of the places but the same result occured.

We want to have the shortes result first.

Any help is appriciated.

Best,
Yavor

Comment: Why are you filtering by `name_bg` but not selecting it? Is this definitely correct?

Comment: Have you considered full text search for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not clear to me why you expect that it should. Does the [length](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length) function do what you need?

```
SELECT id,
       name
FROM   places
WHERE  name_bg LIKE 'рим%'
        OR name LIKE 'рим%'
ORDER  BY Length(name)
```

Comment: I am sorry I oversimplified the case. Turns out the GROUP BY statement is what makes the ORDER go weird. Any way aruond this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to understand that a select-query without an order by clause is essentially unordered. It may appear to have specific order, which usually results in the same way. But this is just the result of the implementation of getting the results. In most cases it is predictable by looking at what index is used. But you should not rely in any way on this.

You can order the resultset by adding an order by clause: probably using the `CHAR_LENGTH` function. A multi-byte character counts as a single character. If the length of the string is equal, again, the ordering is undefined. So, for instance, if you want to make sure results are then ordered by alphabet. Use a second clause stating `name`. It should also be noted that alphabetical ordering is done by the `collation`. So it orders by the bulgarian ordering if this is set to a bulgarian collation.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have an order by clause, you won't get the results back in any definite order.  That can change from query to query.  If you want the shortest result first, order by length(result).